# TypeError: Cannot read property gasUsed of null

Tags: express, mongoose

I continously add data to mongoDb almost after every 1 minute.My data is added but after adding 10 to 15 record it give me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property gasUsed of null".

Comment: my mongoose connection is 
mongoose.connect(url,{
  useMongoclient : true,
  
}).then(()=> console.log('mongo database is connectd')).catch((err)=> console.log("error is ",err.message));

Comment: You have to give us some code to be able to figure out what is happening